# jQuery reverse animation steps / toggle

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-animate, toggle

I have a html structure that needs to animate on click. I have written the first half to achieve this but am unsure how to reverse these steps when the event handler is clicked again.

Code so far http://jsfiddle.net/aYfUH/

Also, is stacking the animate method like this the best way to achieve steps of an animation?

Comment: You can use the `slideToggle()` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, this is how I solved it in the end...

```
function () 
        {
        $ticker = $('.ticker');
        $tickerFull = $ticker.find('.full');
        $tickerMiniExpand = $ticker.find('.expand');
        $tickerMini = $ticker.find('.mini');

        $tickerMiniExpand.on('click', function(e) 
            {
            if ($('.expand.closed').length) 
                {
                $(this).removeClass('closed');
                $(this).addClass('open');
                e.preventDefault();

                $ticker.animate(
                    {
                        top: -30
                    }, 150, function() 
                    {
                        $ticker.animate(
                        {
                            'z-index': 1000,
                    }, 0, function() 
                        {
                        $ticker.animate(
                        {
                            top: 0,
                            height: 331
                        }, 0, function() 
                            {
                            $tickerFull.animate(
                                {
                                    top: 0
                                }, 
                                {
                                    duration:350 
                                });
                            $tickerMini.animate(
                                {
                                    top: 279
                                }, 
                                { 
                                    duration:350 
                                });
                        }); // 2nd animate
                    }); // 1st animate
                }); // click
            } else {
                $(this).removeClass('open');
                $(this).addClass('closed');
                e.preventDefault();

                $tickerMini.animate(
                    {
                        top: 0
                    }, 
                        {
                            duration:200, queue: false 
                        });
                $tickerFull.animate(
                    {
                        top: -279
                    }, 
                        {
                            duration:200, queue: false 
                        });
                $ticker.animate(
                    {
                        top: -30,
                        height: 52
                    },
                        {
                            duration:350, queue: true 
                        })
                .animate(
                    {
                        'z-index': 0,
                    },
                        {
                            duration:0, queue: true 
                        })
                .animate(
                    {
                        top: 0
                    }, 
                        {
                            duration:200 
                        })
                };
            });
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out the `toggle()` method in jQuery: http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

Comment: I changed animate method to toggle and on click it just made everything display none... I have read toggle but cant connect the dots from what I have with animate to that

Answer (score 0):

I thing this is what you need

Some css change

```
.ticker-holder {
    position:relative;
    height:52px;
}

.ticker-holder .ticker {
    width:100%;
    float:left;
    top:0px;
    z-index:0;
    overflow:hidden;
}

.ticker .full {
    height:250px;
    width:960px;
    padding:10px 10px 0px 10px;
    background-color:blue;
    display:none;
}

.ticker-holder .ticker .mini {
    height:30px;
    width:980px;  
    background-color:#000000;    
}​
```

Javascript

```
$('.expand').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $ticker = $('.ticker');
    $tickerFull = $ticker.find('.full');
    $tickerMini = $ticker.find('.mini');

    $tickerFull.slideToggle('slow');
});​
```

[Look at the updated demo](http://jsfiddle.net/thujeevan/aYfUH/1/)

Comment: Where this lives in the project requires it to slide up 30px, change z-index (so when it comes back down it is over the content) etc so I need to have stages in the animation and animate gives me this control, I just dont want to duplicate the code to reverse the animation when I trigger the click again, hence toggle (at least I thought toggle)

Comment: @Adrian Then how the eventual animation should be? You can do it simply with css.

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm late to the party but for new comers here's a little jQuery plugin that I made a while ago that brings support for reverse animations:

https://github.com/ZiadJ/jquery.reversible

I've successfully used it on several projects up to now. Hope this helps.